# The $m$-dimensional Hausdorff measure agrees with the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ when $m=n$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, hausdorff-measure

Let $\alpha_m$ be the Lebesgue measure of the closed unt ball in $\mathbb{R}^m$. For $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, the $m$-dimesnsional Hausdorff measure of $A$ is defined as:
$$
H^m(A) = \lim_{\delta \to 0 } \inf \bigg\{\sum_j \alpha_m \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^m (\text{diam}(S_j))^m \bigg| A \subset \bigcup_j S_j, \ \text{diam}(S_j) < \delta \bigg\} \quad \quad (*)
$$

I'm trying to understand this definition and how the various components of it are motivated.

Suppose $n=m=3$ and that $A$ is the the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$. From what I've read if $m=n$ the Hausdorff measure agrees with the Lebesgue measure so $(*)$ should evaluate to simply $\alpha_m = \alpha_n = \alpha_3 = \frac{4}{3}\pi$. How can this evaluation be performed starting from the definition of the Hausdorff measure in $(*)$?

Comment: In the case $m=n$, once $\delta$ is large enough you can simply attain the infimum by setting $S_1=A,S_j=\emptyset$ for $j>1$, at which point the sum simply reduces to $\alpha_m (\mathrm{diam(A)}/2)^m$ which is of course the actual Lebesgue measure of the ball. This is not very insightful of course.

Comment: There is an error in the definition.  $\delta$ should be taken to zero, not infinity.  Note that this does have an effect on the validity of @Ian's approach.

Comment: With @XanderHenderson's correction (thanks), the situation for $m=n$ is now  the same as the usual construction of the Lebesgue measure: cover the ball by tiny balls and sum up their volumes, and then as the balls becomes smaller, reduce the overlap and reduce the amount of volume located outside the original ball. Again, this isn't very insightful to what this construction means for purposes of dealing with $m \neq n$.

Comment: As for the case $m \neq n$, the idea is to cover $A$ by sets $S_j$ and treat the $m$-dimensional volume of the $S_j$ as being approximated by the volume of a $m$-dimensional ball with the same diameter as the $S_j$. So for example, you might cover a square in the $(x,y)$ plane ($m=2$) with rectangular prisms ($n=3$) which are very short in the $z$ direction and are equal in size in the $x$ and $y$ directions.

Comment: (Cont.) Now $\alpha_2 (\mathrm{diam(S_j)}/2)^2$ is the area of a disk whose diameter is the same as the diameter of the projection of these prisms into the plane. For small disks this area is close to the true area of the projection (which is to say the area of the corresponding square), so you are nearly summing up the area of the squares, which is exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Actually the $n$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $\Bbb R^n$ is equal to _a constant multiple of_ Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Ian Ok thanks..I suppose I'm wondering (i) where the $\alpha_m$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ come from and (ii) why we take $(\text{diam}(S_j))$ to the power $m$? These are the items that distinguish this measure from the Lebesgue measure which simply sums over intervals (i.e. over $(\text{diam}(S_j))$).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think that the normalization used in this definition (which is contrary to, e.g., the Wikipedia definition) avoids that fact.

Comment: @csss The inclusion of $\alpha_m (1/2)^m$ is to normalize $\mathrm{diam}(S_j)^m$ to match up with the actual $m$-dimensional volume of a ball with diameter $\mathrm{diam}(S_j)$. And the power $m$ is just because of scaling: an $m$-dimensional ball's $m$-dimensional volume scales like its diameter to the power $m$. The point here is that when $m<n$ (which is the interesting case) this infimum will be well-approximated by sets which are essentially $m$-dimensional balls stretched very slightly out into the remaining $n-m$ dimensions.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Look at the definition provided in the original question---the constants are included in the definition.  It is a slightly nonstandard definition, but the assertion is correct if the Hausdorff dimension is defined as in ($\ast$).

Comment: @csss To put it another way, when $m=n$, if you restrict the $S_j$ to be balls, this definition is exactly the same as the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @csss What??? Before attempting this problem you need to get the definition  of Lebesgue measure straight! What you say about that definition holds **if** $n=1$.

Comment: @Ian I saw the funny constants, but II was bothered by the fact that if we cover $B(0,1)$ by small balls they must overlap. But yes, it's clearly ok: We can find disjoint small balls that cover all of $B(0,1)$ except a set of measure $\epsilon$, and then cover the leftover part by balls with $\sum r_j^n<c\epsilon$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes I meant when $n=1$.

Comment: @csss Well if you're only talking about $n=1$ then your question about why the $n$ is  there doesn't make much sense - if $n=1$ then $r^n=r$.